# how to ajax a Google maps using phone gap or cordova

Tags: ajax, google-maps, cordova

I've created a PHP file named `maps.php` that contains a simple Google Maps API that works on the iPad's default browser.

But when I call it using Ajax, the page loads itself but not the map. If I open the link in a desktop or mobile browser it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show google maps by accessing google's [javascript api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            myOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can load any php page directly in webView by using `window.location="http://www.mourady.me/alhokair/iphone/maps.php"` javascript method, as your php page contain google map in canvas tag, you can not load that in div through ajax call, better way used iframe tag to the job.

```
<html>
    <body onload="bodyload()">
        <button onclick="bodyload()">Ajax call</button>
        <iframe id="mapDiv" height=500px width=700px src="http://www.mourady.me/alhokair/iphone/maps.php"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but i solved it, but it seems that i was misunderstood. it turned out that i have to load the google maps api in the index page and the ajax that calls the map have only the initialize function not thhe google maps api